# Find an element that has a text value of 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find an element that's text value is 0.

I do:

```
var d = $('.content').find('div');
if(d.text().length === 0){
    //do something
}
```

Is there a way to put the above logic in the selector?

I've tried:

```
var d = $('.content').find('div:empty');
```

But no luck as the div may have other empty html tags in.

Comment: text value or text content length?

Comment: it seems like you are talking about empty content, but your question was asked for a content which equals `0`. So whats your plan?

Comment: Ah sorry, its content that = 0

Comment: Can you post a sample of the HTML you're working with?

Comment: what you are looking for 0 or empty ,first if div has content like this <div>0</div> it is not empty

Answer (score 2):

Use a `filter`

```
var elems = $('.content').find('div').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == 0 });
```

Comment: Probably have to make sure that the `text()` is equal to `'0'` the string and not `0` the number.

Comment: @Loyalar -- `0 == "0"`